# Return content between corresponding brackets

Tags: awk, sed, grep, terminal, regular-expression

I have a file with all type of brackets `{}[]()`- nested, open and close appropriately. I would like to return the content within the matching square brackets after the string (`text:`). The content of the file looks like this:

```
.... 

{
    "text": [
        {
            "string1": ["hello", "world"],
            "string2": ["foo", "bar"]
        },
        {
            "string1": ["alpha", "beta"],
            "string2": ["cat", "dog"]
        }
    ],
    "unwanted": [
        {
            "stuff": ["nonesense"]
        }
    ]
}
.... and so on
```

I would like to return

```
{
    "string1": ["hello", "world"],
    "string2": ["foo", "bar"]
},
{
    "string1": ["alpha", "beta"],
    "string2": ["cat", "dog"]
}
```

The file is `json` type and has similar structure throughout. I would like to return contents in the square brackets after `text:` specifically.

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: You can't parse nested parenthesis with regular expressions (they're not a "regular" language in the technical sense). Then again, Perl supports regexes that aren't limited to being "regular", so you could hack it up with a recent-enough Perl. Or, if it's enough to do that, ignore the brackets and nesting, and just look for the lines that say `text: [` and `]`. Then again, if it's actually proper JSON, and the example is just off, then you should use a JSON parser. But that's something only you know, and you'll have to decide if heuristics are ok, or if you need an exact parse.

Comment: @ilkkachu  Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you've offered isn't valid JSON. Bracketing the expression, fixing up the other errors, and adding a counter-example:

```
{
    "text": [
        {
            "string1": ["hello", "world"],
            "string2": ["foo", "bar"]
        },
        {
            "string1": ["alpha", "beta"],
            "string2": ["cat", "dog"]
        }
    ],
    "unwanted": [
        {
            "stuff": ["nonesense"]
        }
    ]
}
```

You can parse this with a JSON parser such as `jq`. For example, this will pick out the `text` arrays:

```
jq -c '.text[]'

{"string1":["hello","world"],"string2":["foo","bar"]}
{"string1":["alpha","beta"],"string2":["cat","dog"]}
```

Or

```
jq '.text[]'

{
  "string1": [
    "hello",
    "world"
  ],
  "string2": [
    "foo",
    "bar"
  ]
}
{
  "string1": [
    "alpha",
    "beta"
  ],
  "string2": [
    "cat",
    "dog"
  ]
}
```

These are syntactically identical; just laid out slightly differently.

Comment: Thanks. Is there a way to achieve the same without `jq`? Like a conventional string match method?

Comment: @SKPS this is not a conventional string and you are not asking for a string match, so that really isn't the right approach. For example, what would happen if `string2` contained `"he[llo"`? That's perfectly valid, but it would break any naive approach to parsing the data. You could write a little script that keeps track of the open and closed brackets, but is it really worth it?

Comment: @terdon Thanks. I realize it would be more complicated than I think. I will proceed using `jq`.