# Find number of lines between a pattern inside specific filetype

Tags: find, xargs, json, jq, wc

I have a `notes.json` file inside each directory. The following command counts length of each `notes.json` file and returns a sorted output by each file's number of lines.

```
find . -name notes.json | xargs wc -l | sort -nr
```

It returns

```
789 ./D/notes.json
789 ./F/notes.json
574 ./A/notes.json
519 ./G/notes.json
```

Now I would like to include a [search pattern](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/702412/return-content-between-corresponding-brackets) for contents inside `notes.json` and would like to return the sorted number of lines for each `notes.json` file.

I tried `find .  -name notes.json | xargs cat | jq '."text1[]"' | wc -l`. However, I receive only one value i.e. The total number of lines between `text1[ ]` in all `notes.json`. Of course, this is because `cat` outputs the pattern match of all files together. Is there a way to output the line lengths (return from matching pattern) for each `notes.json` file - sorted?

Comment: As [I demonstrated](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/702414/100397) in what seems to be an answer to an earlier part of this question area, counting lines of JSON is meaningless: one of my example answers had 2 lines but the other semantically identical content had 20.

Comment: What shell do you want to use for the solution ? (Is portability important to you ?)

Comment: Is _"It returns"_ (`789 ./D/notes.json` etc.) to be sorted by line numbers? Is that what you want?

Comment: @roaima anyway to achieve what I want here with a one-liner?

Comment: How can you achieve a meaningless measure?

Comment: What's the input and what's the desired output?

Answer (score 0):

- **Not sorting** the output:

Trying this for my own file tree with thousands of json files:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*[0-9].json" \
    -exec bash -c 'printf "%4d %s\n" $(jq ".bbx_basic[]" "$1" | wc -l) "$1"' bashscript {} ';'
[Example output in my tests]
 130 ./Images/Training_set/00000845.json
  13 ./Images/Training_set/00005869.json
  13 ./Images/Training_set/00000991.json
  26 ./Images/Training_set/00005631.json
1013 ./Images/Training_set/00001737.json
...
 410 ./Annot_txt/Coco_en_2017/instances_val2017.json
   0 ./Annot_txt/Coco_en_2017/instances_val2017.json
```

This restricts the search to regular files for the file names specified by my pattern `*[0-9].json` . In your case you would want to execute the following command:

```
 $ find . -type f -name "notes.json" \
     -exec bash -c 'printf "%6d %s\n" $(jq ".text1[]" "$1" | wc -l) "$1"' bashscript {} ';'
```

- **Sorting** the output:

  - The modified command persists the unsorted output in an intermediate temporary file (named `outfile`) in case you want to do more with it, than just sort and send to standard output. You can locate that file in your `/tmp/` directory if you want.
  - Reverse sorting is on the first (numeric) field, and thus should not depend on the specified locale.
  - Sorting starts, when the `find` job executing in the background exits, no matter what its exit status is.

Code:

```
$ find . -type f -name "notes.json" \
    -exec bash -c 'printf "%6d %s\n" $(jq ".text1[]" "$1" | wc -l) "$1" 2>/dev/null >> outfile' bashscript {} ';'; sort -k1,1nr outfile
```

The above can be made more robust and nimble at the same time, with:

```
$ find . -type f -name "notes.json" -exec sh -c '
    for file do
      printf "%6d %s\n" $(jq ".text1[]" "$file" 2>/dev/null | wc -l) "$file"
    done' sh {} + >> outfile; sort -k1,1nr outfile
```

The result is the same but improvements per @StéphaneChazelas' suggestions consist in:

- making it more portable by using `sh` instead of `bash`,
- minimizing the number of shells being spawned by `find ...-exec sh -c '...'` adopting a batch treatment (`+`) instead of a file-by-file treatment (`\;`) of `find`'s results,
- minimizing the number of file descriptor (`output`) openings by redirecting the output of `find` as a whole instead of doing so file-by-file as before.

Comment: I also need the folder containing the `notes.json` and as well need the sorting done as per number of lines. Overall, the output needs to be in the format shown in the question.

Comment: Why the  `& wait $!`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: It is a remnant of previous logic. Now that appending to `outfile` is done batch-wise, it became superfluous. There is no possible race condition with `-exec` any longer and sorting takes place on the final `outfile` when writing to FD ends, not (potentially) piece-wise on `outfile` to which `find` results are appended file-by-file.  There was another reason for not using `&&` instead. In `A && B`, B only ever executes if the exit status of A is 0. Because `find` may sometimes produce "access denied" permission errors, `sort` wouldn't execute. `& wait $!;` solved that.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any logical reasoning why you would need that? One can write lots of records into a single line, because line breaks are not required. I'd rather say that you've chosen the wrong weapon for dealing with [JSON](https://www.json.org/). Therefore I'd suggest to use the [PHP CLI](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php), eg. in order to count the items in a JSON array. Current versions come with a driver for the JSON file-format, by default. The PHP functions to use would be [`get_file_contents()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php), [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) and [`sizeof()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sizeof).

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, I could not do a one-liner for this requirement. The following script solved the problem

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a arr
arr=()
for i in $(find . -name notes.json)
do
  arr+=`(echo $i | xargs cat | jq '.text1[]'  | wc -l); echo $i; echo "\n"`
done
echo -e $arr | sort -nr > out.txt
```

Comment: Related: [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697)